# How to change Android NavigationView's selected item in relation to fragment's popBackStack

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I implemented the new NavigationView (from the support library) and a couple of Fragments, I then overrided the onBackPressed function and added this:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

which returns me to the previous fragment.

So what I need is this: how I can change the navigationview's current selected item to the Fragment it is popping back to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got it,
**Firstly**, i made the instance of the navigation **global and public**.

```
 public NavigationView navigationview;
```

I then added in the onCreate and onResume of my fragment:

```
 NavigationView navigationView = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).navigationview;
 navigationView.getMenu().getItem(index).setChecked(true);
```

and the onResume:

```
 navigationView.getMenu().getItem(index).setChecked(true);
```

This **solved** my problem, Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late but I found a solution that is maybe a little faster to code for Activities that have a large amount of fragments.

(In your activity)

- Implement `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener`
- In onCreate() add `fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);`
- Add Method from interface...

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBackStackChanged() {
      MainActivityFragment f = (MainActivityFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
      //Log.v(TAG, "OnBackStackChanged to fragment with index: " + f.getMenuIndex());
      navigationView.getMenu().getItem(f.getMenuIndex()).setChecked(true);
  }
  ```

(Create an interface in a separate file, name it MainActivityFragment) or whatever your activity is named.

```
public interface MainActivityFragment {
    int getMenuIndex();
}
```

(All fragments that are used in that Activity)

- Implement MainActivityFragment
- Add Method from interface...

  ```
  @Override
  public int getMenuIndex() {
      return 2;
  }
  ```

**It may seem like some extra work but in the long run it makes it pretty easy as all you have to do for new Fragments is implement the Activity's Interface and return the index of it's menu item.**